How to assign ENTER to a shortcut key?
I'm trying to make a list of all videos I play.
To do that, I have a batch file that get the filename and add it to a TXT file.
Then, it call the system default player to run that video.
I can assign a shortcut to this batch file, but I'd like to do that simply using ENTER key.
So, how to override the default behavior of it to call the batch file and not the default player?
In other words, how to press ENTER in a video file and it invoke the batch file and not the system default player instead?
It's not possible to assign ENTER key to a shortcut key, using shortcut properties.
I also tried to use system Registry, like this:
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\GomPlayerLOG]
@="Abrir com GOM Player"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\GomPlayerLOG\command]
@="\"D:\\Programas\\GomPlayer LOG.bat\" \"%1\""

Without success.
=================
Edited:
More info that I should have gave before.
I'd like to list all videos that I play in a TXT file as a LOG.
I could do that using a shortcut to call a batch file that run VLC video player.
While I'm using Directory Opus as Windows Explorer, I can run it through a button or a shortcut (ALT-BACKSPACE).
Like this:
"B:\Programas\GomPlayer - Histórico.bat" {allfilepath$}
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" {allfilepath$}
@nodeselect

The BAT file is:
dir %1 /b >> "D:\Programas\GomPlayer - Histórico.txt"

As we can see, first I send the file path to the TXT file and after that I call the player.
It runs fine and I can get the list of all videos played.
Now, the challenge is to do that, but changing VLC to GomPlayer, my default player.
As it's associated as a default player, the key is now just ENTER.
So, the BAT file would be like this:
if %~x1 == .mkv goto :MKV
if %~x1 == .mp4 goto :MP4
if %~x1 == .jpg goto :JPG

:MKV
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GRETECH\GOMPlayer\GOM.exe" %1

:MP4
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GRETECH\GOMPlayer\GOM.exe" %1

:JPG
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ACD Systems\ACDSee\ACDSee.exe" %1

How to override ENTER on a video file to call the batch file and not the player executable?

So to sum things up, you have a textfile.txt and inside a list of files. You want, that if you open the textfile.txt that it opens with gomplayer? What if you rename the txt file to .pls or another common playlist file that gomplayer supports natively?

One way is to right-click the video file, select open with..., choose app from this pc, browse, select batch file, and check always use this. Should now work.

Thank you, @LPChip. I have to clarify my question.
In fact, I'm trying to do in this way: to select the video file, press ENTER and run the batch file associated, not GomPlayer.exe.
If I press ENTER on a picture file, it would run the default image program.
Thinking in this way, my batch file would recognize the file type and run the program accordingly. I edited my question above.

So my second comment should then work. Right-click the file with the extension you want to attach to your batch script, and select open with, choose program. If this option is not present, hold shift before right-clicking. Make sure you check, always use this program. If you want to go the manual edit route, make sure you edit the registry at HK_CR.ext and not the full name. a .ext can link to another file, but you can also directly put it in .ext, which is far easier.

@LPChip yes, I know how to run by context menu, using right click. But this isn't the question. I barely use the mouse and do want to invoke the batch file through keyboard, and not just that, but using ENTER key.

Yes, but after you associate it once by mouse, it will then work by enter too. Don't forget, enter is the same as double click, so we must change what the double click does too.
